# How to create a new variable from the contents of another variable in python?

Tags: python

May it's very simple question, but I'm stuck here.
I have variable val as `val="mandy"`, now i want to create a list whose name is the content of val. i.e. "mandy". so how to define `mandy=[]` in python.
It's like "$$" equivalent of PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* do something like this in Python, but it's very un-Pythonic to do so (whereas it's a common PHP idiom as I gather). Don't use the language in a way it's not intended to be used.

What you're trying to do is much better done by using a dictionary, a maximally optimized datatype in Python:

```
>>> val = "mandy"
>>> mydict = {}
>>> mydict[val] = []
>>> mydict[val].append("Hello")
>>> mydict[val].append("Mandy")
>>> mydict
{'mandy': ['Hello', 'Mandy']}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no pythonic way to create variables with variable names. Doing so is a bad practice. Instead, use a dictionary:

```
val = "mandy"
mynames = {}
mynames[val] = []
```

You can now access `mynames["mandy"]` to get or modify the list.

Note that you can achieve a php-like behavior in some Python implementations by modifying [`locals`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals), like

```
>>> locals()['mandy'] = []
>>> mandy
[]
```

Doing so is **strongly discouraged** and **will not work** with some Python implementations though.

Comment: No, you shouldn't modify dictionary returned by `locals`.

Comment: e.g. Try `def foo(): locals()['x']=1; return x` in Python 3.x

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus That's precisely what I tried to express with the last sentence. Highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

You can't (without hacks) and shouldn't.

Use a dictionary `values = {"mandy": []}` instead.

<sub>Why would you want a local variable whose name you don't know?! If you know its name at coding-time, use it in a garden-variety assignment. If not, it shouldn't be a local variable.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Use a `dict`. You can create names with `getattr`/`setattr` or playing with `globals()`, but you more than likely don't need it.

```
val = 'foo'
d   = { val: [] }
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
>>> val = 'mandy'
>>> vars()[val] = []
>>> mandy
[]
```

See more details about [vars() builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#vars)

Comment: No, don't do this. "Note: The returned dictionary should not be modified: the effects on the corresponding symbol table are undefined. [3]"

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus  First of all take a look at the last sentence where is a link to python documentation and where you can see the warning about using of this dictionary. Secondly this solution works anyway, despite of the fact that it is not recommended to do so. And in the third this is only one solution that does _exactly_ what the OP wants.

Comment: It sometimes works, sometimes doesn't. It mostly depends on the scope — it's more likely to work in the global one than the local one.

Comment: @Vader: So if someone asks you how to shoot yourself in the foot, you show him how to pull the trigger?

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus  I thought this is clear from docs: http://ideone.com/buhWG http://ideone.com/sOsnS

Comment: @Vader: That argument is moot, you don't need `vars` to modify attributes on a function (and you shouldn't use `vars` for that, either).

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus I never said that you should I just said that you _can_ . I just gave _exact_ answer to the question. Where is the problem? Of course using of any "backdoors" in the language implementation should be avoided.

Comment: @Vader: The problem is that the first solution (`vars()['x'] = 42`) doesn't work, and the second one is neither answering the question nor recommended.

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus The first solution is http://ideone.com/3vxf3 and it works, for everything else I gave the link to the docs with further explanations.